# Visual Studio debug C code in the .dll library from C#. How to load symbols on program load

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-debugging

I have a `.dll` library which I use in C# code. I have successfully configured VS to debug the C code in the `.dll`. But there is a small problem. The symbol file is loaded on the first call to the code from the `.dll` library. Even if I want to step into the first function it does not happen as it has no symbols at this point of time. The second function call can be debugged correctly. How can I force the VS debugger to load symbols on the application startup?

---

PS I have a workaround - dummy function I break C# code on - step into (it does not happen, but forces the symbols load).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't load PDB for DLL that *is not yet loaded*... Can't you just set breakpoints and restart the app?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Indeed I can. Good point.

Comment: @0___________ Hi, does my answer answer your question? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Visual Studio debug C code in the .dll library from C#. How to load
> symbols on program load

**The answer is we can't.**

The dll file is dynamic load. So the pdb of dll will only be loaded when the c function be called.

After setting the breakpoints, turn on the "Enable native code debugging" on C# Project side property settings, the symbol will be load when hitting the breakpoints.